# Let user crop image

Tags: android, android-intent, crop

I am having a hard time in figuring out how to let the user crop the picture.
I would like to give bitmap variable with loaded bitmap to crop the picture before setting it as wallpaper. But I'm failing to do so... Here is that i tried.

First version. = Works as expected BUT the returned image is in poor resolution. Changing the output to higher value doesn't help. As I saw in some post it is not recommended to use camera as not all devices support this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), loaded,null, null);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);              
intent.setData(uri);  
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");  
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);  
intent.putExtra("outputX", 300);  
intent.putExtra("outputY", 300);  
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);  
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);                                  
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Second. Load up image chooser, and crop afterwards. How can I configurate this to load crop directly on my image? Just like in version 1

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setData(uri);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 2);
```

And onActivity result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) { return; }
    if(requestCode == 2) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();  
        if(extras != null ) {  
            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");  
            loaded = photo;
        }
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(loaded);
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

I do not know whever these are the correct methods to make this done, but I hope somebody could point me in the right direction. Which, why, and how to use.

**Update:** I am still waiting for someone to point out how to do it correctly, answers below are working but returning images in poor resolution, so they are not an option to use

Comment: just add the crop method before the user returns to your activity. before u set view.setImageBitmap or whatever thing you doing pass the cropping method.

Comment: @Datenshi I come back with your solution use this link https://github.com/edmodo/cropper ,This is the one demo project code witch one solve your problem.

Comment: @Datenshi Just try this code,I know this time i am not wrong!!

Comment: Thank you. I will try this one then I have free time for that

Answer (score 3):

Ok Dear Here I put my Whole code of Crop Image In Android.
This the Global variable.

```
    //This For Image Crop
        /**
         *  Uri for set image crop option .
         */
        private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
        /**
         *  int for set key and get key from result activity . 
         */
        public final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 0;

/**
     * Bitmap for apply Crop Operation Result.
     */
    private Bitmap _tempOpration;

    //This is Crop Method.

/**
     * Method for apply Crop .
     * @param filePath -  String path of file .
     */
    private void doCrop(String filePath){
        try{
            //New Flow
            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));

            final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            intent.setType("image/*");
            List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

            int size = list.size();
            if (size == 0) 
            {           
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            else 
            {
                intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                if (size == 1) 
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(intent);
                    ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
                    i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                    startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                }

                else
                {
                    for (ResolveInfo res : list) 
                    {
                        final CropOption co = new CropOption();
                        co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                        co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                        co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);
                        co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                        cropOptions.add(co);
                    }

                    CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                    builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item )
                        {
                            startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() 
                    {
                        public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) 
                        {
                            if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) 
                            {
                                getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                                mImageCaptureUri = null;
                            }
                        }
                    } );
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            genHelper.showErrorLog("Error in Crop Function-->"+ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

**This is the  another Class witch use for find Crop Activity  Intent in Application.**

**CropOption Class.**

```
public class CropOption 
{
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}
```

this is use For Display List.

**CropOptionAdapter**

```
public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> 
{
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions    = options;

        mInflater   = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon)).setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Layout File For CropOptionAdapter**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is the resultActivity.witch give the crop image.**

```
/**
     * @see android.app.Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
        switch (requestCode)
        {
        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            if (data == null) 
            {
                genHelper.showToast("No Crop Activity in This");
                return;
            }
            final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) 
            {
                try 
                {

                    _tempOpration=extras.getParcelable("data");
                    imageLayout.setImageBitmap(_tempOpration);
                    _tempOpration=null;

                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
        }

    }
```

//Do This Type It's work on my live app.

**genHelper.showToast("No Crop Activity in This");**

is my general Class to help display toast message and Error Log.

Bestof Luck.

Comment: Your starts loading crop activity, and gets failed to load :\

Comment: @Datenshi dear just use my code it's work in my live app no any issue.and dear i give you my full code.just implement after say.and another this i manage this thing if no any crop found display toast.just check then implement and then review.

Comment: I know it might be my bad usage. I'm looking into it. One question, what kind of uri do you pass to doCrop function? currently I try to pass web url, or the image should be cached into the phone

Comment: Dear just wait few minute i reply with answer

Comment: if your image is store in sdcard in picture folder then give this type path it`s work perfecty try this.File Path===>/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/test02.png

Comment: well I would like to crop image which is not in sdcard. I have bitmap and I would like to call something like doCrop(bitmap). I'm getting uri of the bitmap and pass it to doCrop, but still i get fail to load image toast after choosing application to crop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25827/discussion-between-zala-janaksinh-and-datenshi)

Answer (score 2):

First, variables:

```
final int PIC_CROP = 2;

Uri imageUri;
Bitmap thePic;
```

Before you take a pic from your Camera or your Gallery, put your image into a Uri (imageUri) , use a method called here as "performCrop()" inside try/catch:

```
 private void performCrop(){
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
            intent.setType("image/*");

            List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
            int size = list.size();

            if (size >= 0) {
                intent.setData(imageUri);        
                intent.putExtra("crop", "false");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
                intent.putExtra("scale", true);  
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                Intent i = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, PIC_CROP);  
            } 

        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

On method onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(thePic); //in my case, set the image on screen

        }else{
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to pass drawable as imageuri ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in similar threads, Android does not have an official crop intent
(https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html), so I would stay away from using "com.android.camera.action.CROP".

However, in the time since this question was originally posted, Android has added a new API in Kitkat (level 19) that allows users to summon a crop-this-image-and-set-as-wallpaper Activity. See WallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(), and this might address your original question.

Answer (score -2):

I also had the problem using the camera and `ACTION_PICK` that the returned image was very small despite the passed resolution being much larger. I got around this storing the resulted crop image in a temporary file

```
// temporary storage location, preferably in your cache directory
private final String tempFilePath = "somePath";

// URI instantiated with your temporary storage location
private Uri tempuri = Uri.fromFile(new File(tempFilePath));

// code for startActivityForResult
private final static int ACTIVITY_CROP_IMAGE = 1;
```

and calling the intent like this

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", wallpaperWidth);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", wallpaperHeight);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempuri);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, ACTIVITY_CROP_IMAGE);
```

and then in `onActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) 
        return;

    if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_CROP_IMAGE) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempFilePath);
            if(bmp != null)
            {
                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmp);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(tempFilePath != null)
            {
                File tempFile = new File(tempFilePath);
                if(tempFile.exists())
                {
                    tempFile.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I constructed the above code from the top of my head and didn't actually compile any of it. But the basics are correct and you should get the hang ;-)