# crop issue in android : Image aspect ratio is not maintained

Tags: android, image, crop

I want to crop image using built in crop action. My code is...

```
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                "com.android.camera.action.CROP");

                        intent.setDataAndType(
                                Uri.fromFile(new File(mQueue.sdcardPath)),
                                "image/*");
                        // set crop properties
                        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                        // indicate aspect of desired crop
                        intent.putExtra("aspectX", WallpaperManager
                                .getInstance(getActivity())
                                .getDesiredMinimumWidth());
                        intent.putExtra("aspectY", WallpaperManager
                                .getInstance(getActivity())
                                .getDesiredMinimumHeight());
                        // indicate output X and Y
                        intent.putExtra("outputX", WallpaperManager
                                .getInstance(getActivity())
                                .getDesiredMinimumWidth());
                        intent.putExtra("outputY", WallpaperManager
                                .getInstance(getActivity())
                                .getDesiredMinimumHeight());
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                        intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);

                        File file = new File(mQueue.sdcardPath);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(file));

                        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_ACTION);
```

It open crop intent but highlight view does not maintain size according to image size.
Ex : my iamge is 720x1280 and I crop in galaxy s3(720x1280)  then highlight view should be full as gallery application does. but I can not.

If my image is 1500x1200 then highlight view should be fit in height but it remains small.and i need to stretch by touching it.

Should be like this

[image]

Am I missing any params to get above result??

Comment: May be help ful to you. same question here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115498/let-user-crop-image/15263571#15263571

Comment: It also do same.. I tried it...

Comment: ok then i advice create own cropActivity.implement gesture and do this