# Take photo and pass it to another activity

Tags: android

I want to create simple app where I can take a photo and pass this photo and after that close camera and pass this photo to another activity. I don't know how can I start. Can you give me some examples how can I do that in easy way?

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115498/let-user-crop-image/15263571#15263571

Comment: save photo on sdcard and then pass the address of photo to another activity,then in another activity load photo from sdcard! and there is dozen ways like this to achieve what you want,google it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture image:
    int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("putSomething", true);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Get image whan photo captured through onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        this.photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    }
}
```

You can pass photo by converting photo into byte array and pass through intent

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("photo", image);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Passing big data through intent is not a good practice. It will cause exceptions or slow down your application.

Comment: you can use Bundle                                                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
    bundle.putString("VENUE_NAME", venueName);  
    //Add the bundle to the intent
    i.putExtras(bundle);

Comment: Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
String venName = bundle.getString("VENUE_NAME");