# Android cutting image and upload to server

Tags: android, sql-server

I am trying to create an android app. In this app, i want to select images in galery and cut it.(150*150). Then i want to upload to my server. So i want to select an image in galery, cut image and upload to server. What should i do? In addition to i don't speak english very well. I am so sorry.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This site is built to answer questions about programming; you seem to have forgotten the question you wanted to make.

Comment: do you want to resize your image in size 150 x 150 ..???

Comment: I want to cut image. For example, while you select profil picture in whatsapp, cutting tool automaticly started. I want to like this.

Comment: may this link help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115498/let-user-crop-image